# Do private properties and methods belong inside a TypeScript definition file?

Tags: typescript

The title says it all really.

I am creating a new d.ts file for a custom project in JavaScript. In other projects, where I have used a third party definition file.  There has been a mixture.  Some people include the private properties and methods of a class while others do not.

Is there a correct way? I would assume that the intention of private elements, is for them to remain that way. But technically speaking, anyone can override a private element right (In JS)? I also have concerns that by ignoring them, I leave open some hole. For example if a class has a private `update()` method, which is not defined, then I extend that class, and write an `update()` method. I feel like there is a conflict here.

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the JavaScript implementation, I would avoid exposing private members that are not on the prototype.

Say we have the following JavaScript:

```
var Example = (function () {
    var update = function() {
        alert('Private');
    }

    function Example() {
    }

    Example.prototype.doIt = function () {
        update();
    };
    return Example;
})();
```

If I declare it like this:

```
declare class Example {
    update(): void; // private
    doIt(): void;
}
```

It looks like I could call `super.update()` from a sub class, but this would fail because the `update` function on the super class is not in scope.

In this case, I would leave it out of the declaration to ensure I prevent this class of error (which would occur at runtime).

```
declare class Example {
    doIt(): void;
}
```

If the `update` function was added to the prototype you should add it to the definition (thank you Ryan for the justification for this).

Comment: The reason to always include private members (from the prototype) in classes is so that subclasses know not to define members with the same name (and thus breaking the class entirely for reasons unknowable).

Comment: Great stuff @RyanCavanaugh - updated to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I appreciate the thorough advice.